# Pasar una variable al hub de signal r asp.net - webforms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, signalr

He desarrollado una aplicación web con signal r guiándome de este tutorial: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Broadcast-Real-time-SQL-69dd9fcc

Funciona bien, pero en el tutorial el ID del empleado no es una variable, lo hardcodea en la clase del hub, yo quiero poder pasarle el id del cliente como variable ya que el aplicativo web maneja usuarios. Mi pregunta es, como pasar del lado del cliente javascript o del lado del servidor aspx un valor (codigo del cliente que lo obtengo con cookies) a la clase hub.

He intentado utilizar Context.QueryString["codUsuario"]; pero esto funciona sólo la primera vez que se llama el hub, es decir, cuando inicia la aplicacion, cuando hago un cambio en la base de datos y llama denuevo al hub, el aplicativo se cae y dice que codUsuario es nulo.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno por fin pude resolver  este problema, quizá le ayude a alguien más en el futuro. La solución fue tan simple como crear una variable estática que almacene el Codigo del Usuario, y en el método OnConnected del Hub, asigno el valor del codigo de usuario de esta forma:

```
 CodUsuario=Context.QueryString["CodUsuarioHub"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar variables de sesión para mantener los valores y pasarlos entre formularios(es más sencillo) o bien, utilizar el patrón observer(es más complicado).

Si eliges almacenar valores en las variables de sesión, te recomiendo utilizar otro método para hacer un POST con AJAX desde javascript al formulario cada tanto tiempo y mantener viva tu sesión web.

Te dejo un link donde hay ejemplos de variables de sesión.

Por otra parte, te recomiendo aprovechar este método para mantener viva la sesión y actualizar el DOM mediante webmethods, ajax y jquery.

Saludos.

Espero te sirva.

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=453

Comment: Hola, Gracias por tu ayuda, pero tengo entendido que no se puede utilizar SignalR con Session o Cookies. El problema en sí es que cuando el hub es llamado por segunda ves, el objeto "Context" es nulo, y no puedo acceder ni a cookies ni a queryString.

Comment: Utiliza Singleton a ver si te ayuda esa madre.